# Cannot find symbol error with scanner

Tags: find, symbols

I'm trying to make this program run, but I have one last error that I can't fix. I get an error message when trying to get user input in my lasTal() function. I am surprised about this error because the exact same line of code has worked for me in my other program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nastaord{
    public static int bFinal, cFinal;
    public static int[] tallistaFinal;

    private static int[] lasTal(){
        int[] tallista; //Det vi ska ha talföljden i

        int i = 0;  //räknare för tallista
        while(true){
            System.out.print("Ange tal, eller tryck enter om du är klar: ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            int nytt_tal = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if(input == ""){
                return tallista;}
            tallista[i] = nytt_tal;
            i++;
        }

    }
    private static boolean bcFinns(int[] tallista){
        boolean OK = true;
        for(int b = -9; b <= 9; b++){
            for(int c = -9; c <= 9; c++){
                for(int i = tallista.length; i > 0;i--){
                    OK = tallista[i] == tallista[i-1]*b+c;
                    if(OK == false){
                        break;}

                    }
                if(OK == true){
                    bFinal = b;
                    cFinal = c;
                    tallistaFinal = tallista;
                    return true;}
                }
            }
        return false;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean OK = bcFinns(lasTal());
        if (OK == true){
            System.out.print(tallistaFinal[tallistaFinal.length-1]*bFinal+cFinal);
        }
        if (OK == false){
            System.out.print("No");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my error message:

```
Nastaord.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
                           ^
  symbol:   variable scanner
  location: class Nastaord
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you did not creat a Scanner Object. Use this in lasTal() method at starting to take input from keyboard and u need to initialize "tallista " array.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```